using trino to create or insert a hive table, it throws out the exception "Column 'ENGINE' cannot be null"
when i use trino to create or insert a hive table, it throws out the exception "Column 'ENGINE' cannot be null"
trino version:444
hive version:3.1.3000.7.1.7.1044-1
the error is below:
Caused by: io.trino.hive.thrift.metastore.MetaException: Insert of object "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTableColumnStatistics@26e26638" using statement "INSERT INTO TAB_COL_STATS (CS_ID,AVG_COL_LEN,BIT_VECTOR,CAT_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_TYPE,DB_NAME,BIG_DECIMAL_HIGH_VALUE,BIG_DECIMAL_LOW_VALUE,DOUBLE_HIGH_VALUE,DOUBLE_LOW_VALUE,ENGINE,LAST_ANALYZED,LONG_HIGH_VALUE,LONG_LOW_VALUE,MAX_COL_LEN,NUM_DISTINCTS,NUM_FALSES,NUM_NULLS,NUM_TRUES,TBL_ID,TABLE_NAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" failed : Column 'ENGINE' cannot be null
at io.trino.hive.thrift.metastore.ThriftHiveMetastore$update_table_column_statistics_result$update_table_column_statistics_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
at io.trino.hive.thrift.metastore.ThriftHiveMetastore$update_table_column_statistics_result$update_table_column_statistics_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
at io.trino.hive.thrift.metastore.ThriftHiveMetastore$update_table_column_statistics_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:93)
is there any way to solve the problem, except that change the hive meta table TAB_COL_STATS add a default value on Column 'ENGINE'.
